# html2pdf add content in footer on each page

Tags: php, html2pdf

I have 5-10 table in pdf in which I am showing all the records of that table and each have approx 1000-2000 records. I have try to use below code to make footer on each page but instead of that its showing after completion of table. My template looks like below

```
   <page backtop="0" backbottom="30mm" footer="page" style="font-size: 9pt">
    <table>
        <Records>
    </table>
    <page_footer>
            <table class="page_footer" style="width: 100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 80%; text-align:center">
                        <p style='font-size: 6pt;color:red;'>
                           ...Content...
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </page_footer>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add custom **header and footer** by using mixture of `tcPDF` and `wkhtml2pdf`. Here is an example [html2pdf/tcpdf/example](https://github.com/iafan/html2pdf/blob/master/_tcpdf_5.9.206/examples/example_003.php) . Here is another example [html2fpdf/discussion/thread](http://sourceforge.net/p/html2fpdf/discussion/391791/thread/e27f4051/)